# User Admin of SharePoint in a client Desktop WIndows Application

Tags: .net, sharepoint, forms-authentication, sharepoint-2013

**Background:**

I've created a client application to connect to SharePoint (2013) on my server (Windows 2008 R2) and download/upload files. I've implemented Forms Based Authentication, by working through the following:

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/

This works fine and I've added the FBA pack (https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/) to administer users on the server.

**Problem**

Now I need to provide user administration (add, delete, edit etc) in my .NET Windows Application which connects to the SharePoint site via the Sharepoint Client API (it's actually an Office VSTO addin) and I'm having trouble working out how to start.

**Question**

I wondered if anyone could give me some advice on the best way to go about this. I'm using the SharePoint Client API in the application and ideally I'd like to use that to add users. But perhaps I need to access the aspnetdb database on SQL Server directly or perhaps I need to create a separate web service to add users to both the aspnetdb and SharePoint

I've seen several articles surrounding this topic and posted on another forum, but I just wanted to hear some thoughts on the best method before I start. I'm new to this area and I want to start off on the correct track, so any advice appreciated.

Thanks